# set interval function is calling more than once but randomly

Tags: javascript, game-engine

Hi im making game and for enemy atack i want to use setInterval witch would execute attacking function.
Problem is, when set interval executes it calls function more than once, not like after set time but in one execution process more than once

this is the specific code that doesnt work as it should

```
var setAttack = function(){
            intr ++;
            entity.attack(entity.wepon, dt);
            var isColliding = collides(entity.wepon, target.entity);
            if(isColliding)
            {
                target.stats.health -= 1;
                console.log(target.stats.health);   
            }

        }

        if((attalumsFromTargetX >= -42) && (attalumsFromTargetX <= 42)) 
        {

            att = setInterval(setAttack, 2000);

        }
```

this is link on full file - https://github.com/Reenasyoo/Purplust/blob/master/src/entity.js

entity.attack() starts at 230 line
then setAttack() starts at 282 line

so when the setInterval starts its thing, setAttack function is called random times in one execution time

i hope somebody understood what i tryed to say!
btw im using rAf for animation!

thankyou in advance!

Comment: When the if statement is executed multiple times there will be more setintervals. use console.log() to debug within the if statement.

if((attalumsFromTargetX >= -42) && (attalumsFromTargetX <= 42)) 
        {
            console.log('setInterval');
            att = setInterval(setAttack, 2000);

        }

Comment: when you see setInterval in the javascript console for multiple times, then you have identified your problem. I would recommend a statemachine for artificial intelligence in javascript. Playing around with setTimeout or setInterval is not the best way to go for games

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use this:

```
      att = setTimeout(setAttack, 2000);
```

Instead of

```
      att = setInterval(setAttack, 2000);
```

Comment: i need to execute setAttack function every 2 sec, not yust once, but in that one executon once not random times. if you dont get my idea download git, and try it, in console you will see my problem. try refresh few times. you can move with a and d.